# lightest way to join 2 CSV (like an SQL LEFT JOIN)

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, left-join

I'm reling on community expertise to guide me in the best way about following topic.

In a professional context runing on windows without possibility to install MS-Office application I need to distribut to my team a way to join 2 CSV files and produce a 3rd CSV files as output. Exactly as if we run a SQL query like :

```
SELECT f1.*, f1.bar = f2.bar as baz 
FROM CSVfile1 as f1 
LEFT JOIN CSVfile2 as f2 
ON f1.key = f2.key
```

Aims is currently reached with Excel + VBA but MS-office package will be removed and no more accessibly. A solution with MS-Acces is not envisageable because of the same reason.

The goal is to allow any body to actualise the 3rd CSV without any competence and specific installation on it Computer. So an approach with python or MS-SQL-Servr is not good also.

I was thinking to accomplish that with Powshell script but first. I'm not habit to use PowerShell but I can learn.

But before trying that I ask to the community if this is the best way ? Or if there is better solution ? (requirements: Windows OS (latest version), No MS-office, No specific install).

Thank you all.

Comment: if the files are large ... use something like sqlite and do the work there. ///// there are several "join csv" scripts on the PSGallery site. they seem to work fairly well. ///// alternately, you may want to look into the hashset class. HashSet<T> Class (System.Collections.Generic) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0 ///// there are several posts about how to use that from inside PoSh on the web. [*grin*]

Comment: ignoring "No specific install" maybe the module "ImportExcel" could help with that https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.2 (which opposed to it's name can do more than just import)

Comment: Please write my code for me is an inquiry, not an answerable question. Stack Overflow is for the latter.

Comment: The asker is asking if this is the best way.  That's not asking for the code.

Comment: Exactly Walter Mitty. I'm familiar with processing via VBA but recently compagny is removing MS licences. I'm pretty sure I can process my CSV's with python if it's for my own machine but I don't want to ask >100 people to install python on they Computer. I'm juste looking which méthode allow me to code the processing and other to launch it even if they have no knowledge and now specific soft installed.

Comment: Lee-dailey --> thx --> I will test your PoSh approach. About SQlite, I'm not really confident in my skill to deploy a one click solution in SQLlite. I only perform on basic 5 hours training. Is that simple? (Shall I précise that other users will have no particular computing skills and I don't want to bother them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PowerShell has no built-in join functionality (akin to SQL's<sup>[1]</sup>) as of v7.2**, though adding a `Join-Object` cmdlet is being proposed in [GitHub issue #14994](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994); third-party solutions *are* available, via the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com) (e.g., [`JoinModule`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule)).

For now, if installing third-party tools isn't an option, you can **roll your own solution** with the following approach, which uses[`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) to load the CSV files, an auxiliary [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) to find corresponding rows, and [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) to add columns (properties).

```sh
# Create sample CSV files.
$csv2 = @'
key,bar,quux
key1,bar1,quux1
key2,bar2,quux2
key3,bar3,quux3
'@ > ./CSVFile1.csv

@'
key,bar
key1,bar1
key2,bar2a
'@ > ./CSVFile2.csv

# Import the the 2nd file and load its rows 
# (as objects with properties reflecting the columns)
# into a hashtable, keyed by the column 'key' values.
$hash = @{}
foreach ($row in Import-Csv ./CSVFile2.csv) {
  $hash[$row.key] = $row
}

# Import the 1st file and process each row (object):
# Look for a matching object from the 2nd file and add 
# a calculated column derived from both objects to the
# input object.
Import-Csv ./CSVFile1.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $matching = $hash[$_.key]
  $_ |
    Add-Member -PassThru baz $(if ($matching) { [int] ($matching.bar -eq $_.bar) })
}
```

Pipe the last statement to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to export the resulting objects to a CSV file.
(E.g.
`... | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 Results.csv`)

The above yields the following:

```
key  bar  quux  baz
---  ---  ----  ---
key1 bar1 quux1   1
key2 bar2 quux2   0
key3 bar3 quux3
```

---

<sup>[1] There is a [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join), but its purpose is to join the elements of a *single array* to form a *single string*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's an off the wall answer using the sqlite command-line shell (a single 900kb executable) and the same sql join command.  https://sqlite.org/download.html  Sqlite seems to have trouble with utf16 or "unicode" text files.  Even Excel has more trouble importing a utf16 csv.

```sh
# making csv file with ">" (utf16) caused this error:
# CREATE TABLE csvfile1(...) failed: duplicate column name:

'key,bar,quux
key1,bar1,quux1
key2,bar2,quux2
key3,bar3,quux3' | set-content csvfile1.csv

'key,bar
key1,bar1
key2,bar2a' | set-content csvfile2.csv

'.mode csv
.import csvfile1.csv csvfile1
.import csvfile2.csv csvfile2
.headers on
SELECT f1.*, f1.bar = f2.bar as baz 
FROM CSVfile1 as f1 
LEFT JOIN CSVfile2 as f2 
ON f1.key = f2.key' | .\sqlite3

# output

# key,bar,quux,baz
# key1,bar1,quux1,1
# key2,bar2,quux2,0
# key3,bar3,quux3,
```

Comment: Not an option per the requirements of the question ("no specific install"), but kudos for a straightforward [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) solution.

Comment: You made me reconsidering my requirement. I will study how to implement SQlite solution Vs PoSh solution. Maybe SQlite can be used easily by my team with a good instruction guide. (I guess they will have to install SQlite first and I need to explain the benefit to do that).

Comment: There's also sqlite studio if you prefer a graphic interface.